# __signature__ assignment doesn't work from inside a function

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'd like to implement a signature preserving decorator. Consider this code:

```
def decorator(func):
    def new_function(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    new_function.__signature__ = inspect.signature(func)
    new_function.__name__ = "test __name__"
    new_function.__doc__ = "test __doc__"
    new_function.__qualname__ = "test __qualname__"
    new_function.__kwdefaults__ = getattr(func, '__kwdefaults__', None)
    new_function.__dict__ = getattr(func, '__dict__', None)
    return new_function


def a(a, b, c=1):
    pass


a2 = decorator(a)
print(a2.__name__)
print(a2.__qualname__)
print(a2.__doc__)
print(inspect.signature(a2))
print(a2.__signature__)
```

All's well with setting `__name__`, `__doc__` and `__qualname__`, but `__signature__` doesn't get set.

Output:

```
test __name__
test __qualname__
test __doc__
(*args, **kwargs)   # <-- not preserved
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_decorators.py", line 57, in <module>
    print(a2.__signature__)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__signature__'
```

This, on the other hand, works:

```
def a(arg1, arg2):
    pass


def b(*args, **kwargs):
    pass


b.__signature__ = inspect.signature(a)
print(inspect.signature(b))  # (arg1, arg2)
print(b.__signature__)  # (arg1, arg2)
```

It seems like for some reason I'm unable to set the `__signature__` field of a `function` object inside another function call. But why? I'm sure it worked some time ago. Every other thing is settable, the `__name__`, the `__qualname__`, etc.

Is this a bug? Am I missing something really obvious? Why is this happening?

I'm running Windows 10 with `Python 3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`.

Comment: Because `new_function.__dict__ = getattr(func, '__dict__', None)` wipes out everything you previously set in `new_function.__dict__`. Why do you do that _last_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I feel so stupid at the moment. I really panicked, I've written a lot of code and it all went kaboom on me, haha. You're a lifesaver, I should've learnt what each special field is for before modifying them. Thank you.

Comment: @jonrsharpe just didn't learn the meaning of `__dict__`. `__signature__` seems to not be the special field, even though it looks like it and is used inside `stdlib` functions like `inspect.signature`. So I didn't consider it would replace the `__signature__` field I set for that reason. Should've thought though.

Comment: You'd be better off just using [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), it sets `__wrapped__` (which is used for determining the signature per https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/#implementation) along with the `__doc__` etc.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the tip, that's where I've got the code from, haha. Except for the part where I screwed up, lol. I just needed a little more from the code. I wanna have a reference to the originally decorated function from each decorator's body. `__wrapped__` of `__wrapped__` of `__wrapped__` of ... That's why I'm going this way.

Comment: You'd already get that with `@wraps`; if you applied multiple decorators, all using `@wraps`, you can chain back through each layer of decoration: `func.__wrapped__.__wrapped__....`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yeah you're right, pointless in fact. I wanted to save the result as `__originalfunc__` generating it the same way you said, but it's just redundant. Sorry, heh.